# Progress Dialog giving error in only one activity

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have some activities in which I am calling progress dialogs until data is fetched from background. In all the other activities, the progress dialog is showing up except in one.

Calling Progress Dialog like so

```
_instance.showDialog(0);
```

OnCreateDialog---

```
    @Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 0:
        p = new ProgressDialog(this);
        p.setTitle(AppConstants.PLEASE_WAIT);
        p.setCancelable(false);

        return p;

    }
    return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}
```

onClose---

```
    public void closeDialog(int id) {
    System.out.println("Progress Dialod Id ------"+ id);
    this.dismissDialog(id);
}
```

Getting the error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no dialog with id 0 was ever shown via Activity#showDialog

Debugged the issue. But getting the id value 0 in both onCreate and closeDialog methods also.

Edit: Tried changing the id to unique like 111. But still dialog not showing up. Similar code is working in another activities.

Comment: Post more related code. Or probably you cannot use the ID as 0 (zero).

Comment: Tried changing the id to unique like 111. But still dialog not showing up. Similar code is working in another activities.